# SKStoreProductViewController can't download app

Tags: iphone, ios6, storekit

i am using SKStoreProductViewController, if i try to download app using real account alert says that i must use test user, but when i use test user the result is below

[image]

app should released tomorrow and 
any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SKStoreProductViewController` has special behavior during development. When you release the app, it will work fine for purchasing items.

Comment: It's inconvenient as certain flows can't be tested until release.

Comment: Looks similar issue I got. Either it said "wrong password", or nothing started except rotating for a while after "Get" tapped.